# Showing powers to numbers powered by minus number

Tags: c

my program is working well but if I put negative number as power it just print me numbers from 1 to 20, whats the problem? I am just a begginer in this and I did not foudn any answer on the internet so I hope I will find some here, you helped me before too. Thank you and looking forward to you advices!

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double xToNPower (double mocnenec, double mocnitel);

int main(void)
{
    double pole[20];
    int i;
    double mocnina;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        pole[i] = i + 1;
    }
    printf("Zadaj mocninu: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &mocnina);
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        pole[i] = xToNPower(pole[i], mocnina);
        printf("%.3lf ", pole[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

double  xToNPower (double mocnenec, double mocnitel)
{
    double x = mocnenec;
    int j;
    if (mocnitel == 0)
    {
     return 1;
    }
    else if (mocnitel == 1)
    {
        return mocnenec;
    }
    else
    {
        for(j=2; j<=mocnitel; j++)
        {
            x *= mocnenec;
        }
        return x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(j=2; j<=mocnitel; j++)` is not going to loop when `mocnitel < 0`. The whole algorithm is flawed though: you pass `double mocnitel` but it only works with a non-negative *integer* value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `xToNPower(pole[i], mocnina);` with `mocnina < 0`, then in `double  xToNPower (double mocnenec, double mocnitel)`, the argument `mocnitel` will be negative as well.

Control drops into the `else` clause, because `mocnitel` does not equal 0 or 1.

This loop is the problem:

```
for(j=2; j<=mocnitel; j++)
{
    x *= mocnenec;
}
```

What if `mocnitel < 0`? Well, the whole loop is simply going to be skipped (since `j <= mocnitel` will be false even before the first iteration), and the next statement, `return x;`, will be executed.

Thus, you got `double x = mocnenec;` as your result - the original number.